# Make a <td> act as a <tr> (table-row) INSIDE an umbrella <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Variations of this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer to my specific question. Here goes:

I have a `table` that I need to be able to sort, using a javascript plugin like ListJS. That's not important, but to be able to I **NEED** a **SINGLE** `<tr>` **PER** listing.

So my table looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line2">line 2</td>
    <td class="line3">line 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6zadmhd/

What I need is `<td class="line2">` and `<td class="line3">` placed below the "first line" of `<td>`'s, making them act as a second and third table-row.

I've tried `display:block;` and `display:table-row;` on `.line2` and `.line3`, but as you can see I'm not getting the desired result.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** This is my expected DESIGN output: http://jsfiddle.net/op5cb4qt/

Comment: could you post your expected output design..its not clear what you want

Comment: Sure, see http://jsfiddle.net/op5cb4qt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is indeed to reset `display`, you can use the flex boxmodel to entirely break the `table-layout`:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}
table,
.line2,
.line3 {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
td {
  display:block;/* IE fix */
  margin: 1px;
}
.line1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
.line2,
.line3 {
  background: blue;
}
.line3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line2">line 2</td>
    <td class="line3">line 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6zadmhd/1/

But why not use regular tags **if** that is not a table ?

to go further with flex, you may read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hey, that looks exactly like I pictured it! So this is using Flexbox? Interesting. Re: regular tags -- do you mean just using another <tr>? That's not possible because of the js sorting constraints.

Comment: @TraceDeCoy yes , flexbox is quiet powerfull and easy to set for nowdays browser. see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @TraceDeCoy no i meant div, footer, arrticle, section or p. whatever reflects the content if that was not a real table

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and while beautiful and effective, I think the float solution is even simpler.

Comment: @TraceDeCoy with float, element of a same row might have different heights and if you need some margins around it calc() comes handy ... http://jsfiddle.net/t6zadmhd/3/ i believe flex is easier and more efficient than float ;)

Comment: You know what, I think you're right. I actually was trying to circumvent the different heights, which led me back here. Accepting yours instead.

Comment: How do I specify each <td>'s width when using flex?

Comment: @TraceDeCoy do you have an example of what/which td you want to resize ? . you can use class, or nth-child(n)

Comment: Resurrecting this because it's completely messed up in IE, and I only just found out. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @TraceDeCoy do you have a link/sample that i could see what's going on ? (wich IE is involved ?)

Comment: @TraceDeCoy never mind, i checked the fiddle. You need to reset display on td also to totally break the table layout) : http://jsfiddle.net/t6zadmhd/4/  (answer also updated with CSS and Comment) Thnaks for the feed back ;)

Comment: GCyrillus, it's me who needs to thank you, so thanks - looks like it's working, and far simpler than what I myself had been cooking up. Quick question if I may: Say I want to specify widths for each of the line1 <td>s, how do I do that? If I just substitute "flex:1" with each width I need, in percentage, adding them up to 100 doesn't work - the line breaks. Even if I remove the "margin:1px"

Comment: Nevermind: flex-basis: XX%; seems to do the trick! Thanks again dude, life saver.

Answer (score 1):

```css
tr{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}
.line2, .line3{width:100%;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line2">line 2</td>
    <td class="line3">line 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do I specify each <td>'s width when using flex?

Comment: You can set `.line1: width: 100px;` it makes the all table width increase. But if you set dynamic width `.line1: width: 24%;` , It does not change the table width. And you set that to `25%` the fourth td `.line1` wraps to next line, Because they have border and `4*25% + 8px` is more than `100%`

Comment: If I set a percentage width on each <td>, do I still need "flex: 1;" on them as well?

Comment: The flex property is for setting the width of items (when flex direction is set to row by default).Therefore when you set width, you do not need to `flex: 1`.

Comment: Flex is very very useful. I suggest you to read this easy and comprehensive article about that: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thanks Farzin, I've already read that and the one at CSStricks, but struggling a bit to understand exactly what does what. I'll get there though :)

Comment: Bring this back to life because I just found out it doesn't look right in IE. Do you have any idea why not, and what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using only `display: block;` but you must set percent width.

```
td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.line1 {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
}

.line2 {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.line3 {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of accomplishing this.  Flex is the most convenient and you are not required to use a table for this.   However if you have any older browser requirements flex could limit you, but float can accomplish what you are asking for without the use of flex.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeb03gts/2/

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table, tr, td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
tr {
  clear:both;
}
.line1 {
    background: #f00;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.line2 {
    background: #00f;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.line3 {
    background: #008000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line1">line 1</td>
    <td class="line2">line 2</td>
    <td class="line3">line 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```